# Getting Tether.js warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting warning in console.

WARNING in ./~/reactstrap-tether/dist/js/tether.js
Critical dependencies:
2:479-486 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/reactstrap-tether/dist/js/tether.js 2:479-486